# How to make flowcover like image slider(jquery editing)

Tags: jquery, css

As you can see on my website : http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/today

I have installed this js slider plugin : http://darsa.in/sly/

I was wondering if it is possible to turn this into apple coverflow like slider.

the only thing that needs to change is the slider boxes to have 3d perspective effects, if you see what i mean.

so it has to look like this with boxes on the side scales down a bit,
and scales up when clicked or activated.

also, the transitioning should be smooth, not rigid like the current one.

This will take direct modification of the js file.

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesnt look like you will have to edit the js. i added these styles to the slider on your page and got a coverflow-like effect. you may need to tweak them to your liking but you get a similar effect.

```
.frame ul{
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.frame ul li{
    transition: transform .3s;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.frame ul li:not(.active){
    transform: rotateY(-100deg);
}
```

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't work the way i expected. it has to look like this rather http://imgur.com/IbBiOss and is it :not(.active) or.active? im confused here.

Comment: What the :not selector is doing is targeting all the li elements that do not have the active class.

Comment: i see.  sorry, i didn't know that. if you go to my website, you can see how it's not working so well, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah it looked better when i added the styles directly. my guess is that sly does its calculations based on the width of the li elements. if there is a callback for sly you can add the styles once the initial slider dimensions have been sent. does that make sense?

Comment: not really, but i think i get the sense of what you are trying to say. again, thanks for your help. i might try to come back to it some time later as right now, the styling is't really the important issue. but if you could figure out something, would you be kind to tell me what you know? that would be appreciated a lot. thanks.